# Google Maps V2 position camera to fit entire street

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a search field with Google Places autocomplete suggestions. When a street is clicked, I make a call to Google Places to get more info for that place.
`Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, id).setResultCallback(callback);`

With the callback:

```
ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Place place = places.get(0);

                if (place.getLatLng() != null)
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(place.getViewport(), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.places_zoom_padding)));
                else
                    ToastUtils.showMessage(R.string.error_could_not_find_place_location);
            } else {
                ToastUtils.showMessage(R.string.error_could_not_find_place_location);
            }

            //Release the PlaceBuffer to prevent a memory leak
            places.release();
        }
    }
```

The place's **viewport** doesn't fit my needs because it doesn't fit the entire street in the map, instead it usually zooms in on the center of the street.
**I need** a way to determine **the start and finish coordinates of the street**. This way I can create a LatLngBounds based on those and position the map.